# Finite Precision Arithmetic Coding Decoding Process?

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, compression

I've been doing some reading on arithmetic coding, particularly how to deal with finite precision, so for example, when the range is inside the interval (0, 0.5) or (0.5, 1), one can just output 0 or 1 respectively, and then double the range. What I don't understand is if this process is adopted, how does one go about decoding the resulting code?

Answer (score 2):

The decoder runs an exact duplicate of the encoder (necessarily delayed with respect to the original), including its encoding interval model.

The decoder also keeps track of the known output interval of the encoder, up to the point at which it has read the compressed datastream.  When this interval fits inside one of the intervals of the encoding model, it knows it can decode the corresponding symbol.

---

Note that, while reading the compressed datastream, the output interval can quickly be reduced to a size of 1 (the smallest step the finite-precision encoder can represent).  Since the encoding intervals are all discretized, this unit output interval is guaranteed to fit into some encoding interval, so the decoder can never fall too far behind the encoder.  However, the end of a compressed stream may require a "flush" of the decode state -- either by some auxiliary signal (like a file length), or by the encoder sending enough extra bits to ensure that the decoder finds its termination symbol.